# ¿Para que sirve LEA en ensamblador?

Tags: ensamblador, masm

Esto es lo que he leído sobre LEA:

*Carga la dirección del operando fuente.*

**Sintaxis**:

```
LEA destino, fuente
```

El operando fuente debe estar ubicado en memoria, y se coloca su desplazamiento en el registro índice o apuntador especificado en destino.

**Ejemplo:**

```
MOV SI, OFFSET VAR1
```

*Que es equivalente a:*

```
LEA SI, VAR1
```

Cómo tampoco sabía que era un offset busqué en y encontré en Wikipedia lo siguiente:

Dado un array de caracteres A que contenga `"abcdef"`, se puede decir que el elemento que contiene el caracter `'d'` tiene un **offset** de **4** desde el **comienzo** de **A**.

Por lo que he entendido que en el ejemplo de **LEA** en el registro **SI** se guarda el tamaño de la cadena **VAR1** para que se sepa cual es el último índice de la cadena.

Comment: En el ejemplo, el OFFSET de VAR1 es el desplazamiento de VAR1 con respecto al inicio del segmento de datos, es decir, es el comienzo de VAR1, no el final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`LEA` de Load Effective Address](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_153.html):

**TL;DR**

Computa la dirección absoluta o efectiva de un *offset* o posición de memoria y la guarda en el operando de destino sin alterar ninguna bandera.

---

Considera el siguiente ejemplo:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 'h' | 'o' | 'l' | 'a' | <- Valor del array de caracteres "A"
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  | <-Posición en memoria
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

En C, si hacemos `A[0]`, el valor retornado debería ser `'h'`, no? Entonces, la instrucción `LEA` en ensamblador hace prácticamente lo mismo, con la diferencia de que el valor no es [*dereferenciado*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224831/meaning-of-referencing-and-dereferencing), sino que solo se carga la direccion resultante en el operando de destino.

---

*El siguiente texto fue tomado de una [respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)*.

Imagina que tienes la siguiente estructura:

```
struct Point {
    int xcoord, ycoord;
};
```

Y defines un array de esa estructura, luego intentas acceder a un elemento del array mediante:

```
int y = points[i].ycoord; /* Accede al elemento en la posicion [i].  */
```

Entonces, asumiendo que la dirección base, es decir, que el elemento `[0]` del array este en `EBX` y la variable `i` en `EAX`, tienes la siguiente instrucción:

```
MOV EDX, [EBX + 8*EAX + 4]  ; El lado derecho es la "Dirección efectiva"
```

Y esto te dara como resultado **el valor** de la variable `y` en `EDX`; la razon del `8` en el lado derecho es que actualmente el tamaño de la estructura `Point` es `8` bytes.

Ahora considera que ejecutas lo siguiente en tu programa, en lugar de asignar el valor, asignas la dirección de memoria de la variable `ycoord` del indice `i` en el array.

```
int *p = &points[i].ycoord; /* Crea un puntero a points[i].ycoord */
```

El resultado en ensamblador sera:

```
LEA ESI, [EBX + 8*EAX + 4] ; Carga solo la dirección de memoria.
```

En este caso no querías asignar el valor de `ycoord` en el indice `i` de tu array, en su lugar, creaste un puntero y lo asignaste a `ESI`.

Cambiando todo eso, y asumiendo que el indice al que intentas acceder es `4` y que la direccion de `array[0]` es cero, el código realiza los siguientes cálculos:

```
LEA ESI, [0         + 8      *      4 + 4]
          Dirección | Tamaño x Indice + Offset 
          base                          de variable necesitada.
```

Cabe mencionar que este ejemplo es valido para el código puesto mas arriba, por lo que puede cambiar.

Answer (score 3):

```
LEA reg, mem
```

Carga la dirección efectiva de `mem` en `reg`. Es decir, `reg` pasa a contener un puntero a `mem`.

En contraste a:

```
MOV reg, mem
```

que carga el valor contenido en `mem` en `reg`.

En contraste a:

```
MOV reg, imm
```

que carga un operando inmediato codificado en la instrucción en `reg`. Esta sería la instrucción generada cuando el ensamblador lee `MOV reg, OFFSET etiqueta`.

---

Aunque `LEA` esté pensada para usar un registro como un puntero, muchas veces se utiliza para otras cosas, por ejemplo, como un NOP de varios bytes (`LEA ESI, 0[ESI]`), para multiplicar un número por 5 (`LEA reg, [reg+4*reg]`), ...

Answer (score 0):

LEA realiza la carga del valor de desplazamiento de la memoria en un registro.

http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/I77_0190_lea_instruction.htm

Comment: Hola. No recomendamos agregar links, porque estos se terminan cayendo y no ayudan a los usuarios futuros. Por favor, podrías agregar en tu respuesta una síntesis del link? gracias. Mira [answer]